# Is there a best practice for the files field in the package.json?

Tags: node.js, npm

In the **package.json** file I set `"files": ["./src", "/.lib"]`

This entry in the package.json is supposed to do this:

> The optional files field is an array of file patterns that describes the entries to be included when your package is installed as a dependency.

[From npm docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json)

My code is currently compiled from Typescript code at `./src` to Javascript code at `./lib`. The source code is actually available publicly on Github.

Is it redundant to add the source folder to the package? This will increase the size of data from the package as well.

On the other hand, this may help others to spot bugs.

What would be the best practice for this case?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, it's better to include the source. The reasons are as follows:

1. Your compilation settings (like the target) may not be what the user wants sometimes (let's say if they needed support for an old browser or older version of Node) and so they want to compile it from source themselves for whatever reason.
2. It's often very helpful during debugging. Editing the compiled source is noisy but if they are debugging it in situ in their project, they can switch to the source and edit that in `node_modules`. This can be useful when trying to understand bugs or how the library works.

Worth noting when a user does this it's usually assumed they are on their own in terms of support. But the escape hatch can be useful.

Comment: It's also worth noting that SO does not allow questions asking for opinion. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)